# How to enable alt-tab to browse windows?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic

I am using gnome classical (without effects), and recently alt-tab stopped working to switch windows.

How to enable alt-tab to switch windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Compiz Config Settings Manager:

To open terminal hit Alt+Ctrl+T and run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Or search for compizconfig-settings-manager in Software Center and install from there.

Then go to system tools > preferences > compizconfig

Go at the very bottom where it says windows management (or something similar.)

Put a checkmark in application switcher

That should fix it.

Comment: I installed this manager this week and found nothing called "application switcher" under Window Management (or any other category). Any suggestions what I should do next?